# plotly::renderPlotly() does not allow for NULL values. How can I workaround?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Title says it basically. For a complex Shiny App I have to be able to send NULL values to `renderPlotly()`, because I want to display a plot only when certain conditions are met. The normal `shiny::renderPlot()` is able to do this.
A small example which gives an error I do not want:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plotly"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # I need to be able to put NULL in here or anything so that
  # there is no output and also no error message.
  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    NULL
  })

  # This works and sends no error message
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    NULL
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that the Web App displays only one error message, the one from `renderPlotly()`.
I am looking for any workaround to this. How can I switch between those two plots which should be displayed at the same spot in the app, and always ignore one of them, depending on other input?

Comment: Have you considered this: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html?

Comment: Didn't see this before. Can the conditionalpanel access objects from the server function? Meaning, can I access conditions which are rendered from the server?

Comment: I think that chould be possible. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710455/shiny-conditionalpanel-set-condition-as-output-from-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using `shiny::conditionalPanel`. Plotly plot is shown only when certain condition is met.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("shouldShow", "show plot", c("yes", "no"), "yes"),
    conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.shouldShow == 'yes'",
        plotlyOutput("foo")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$foo <- renderPlotly({
        gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()
        ggplotly(gg)
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is it possible that the conditional panel depends on a condition which is created in the server part?

Comment: @Stan125 Yes. Can you give an example what you mean by "in server". If loaded file size was bigger than something or what?

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize the plotly_empty() function when your data is null.

Assuming you assign your plotly (or NULL) to a variable called 'myplotly', you can use the following:

```
  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    if(is.null(myplotly)) plotly_empty() else myplotly
  })
```